# Aligning two TextViews in a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

How do I align two TextViews with different font sizes in a RelativeLayout so that they're baseline aligned?

[image: Like this]

The bottom image is when both text views have `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` but they're the same way if I use `android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/leftTextView"` on the right text view.

What would be super useful is some way to make sure that the tops of the letters in two text views also align, but that's probably not realistic for TextViews.

By demand, the code

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/leftTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="@string/daily_average_month"
    style="@style/tvStatName" />

    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/rightTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  
    style="@style/tvStatValue.big" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your code? It is easier that way to debug by copying over and trying out some parameters..

Comment: you could keep the two textViews inside a `LinearLayout` and align that `LinearLayout` as a whole.

Comment: BOth text views in one linear layout? how would that make them align differently than in a relative layout?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

use `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` for `rightTextView` and try

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/leftTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="@string/daily_average_month"
    style="@style/tvStatName" />

    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/rightTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    style="@style/tvStatValue.big" />
</RelativeLayout>
```